# How do I install a Python package in the form of a folder from my downloads folder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am working on a project at work that would be MUCH easier if it was written in Python instead of R. However, I can only use Spyder (from Anaconda) which comes with preinstalled packages. Our IT has blocked pip install so I downloaded the relevant packages from PyPI (Selenium) and it's sitting in my downloads folder as an unzipped folder. I cannot put these folders into the library directory, which IT has also blocked access to.

Is there any way to install these downloaded packages? It would make my teams life 10x easier.

Thanks

Comment: You said: "Our IT has blocked pip install". That's really wise! Mixing pip and conda packages is the number one cause of headaches, segfaults, DLL issues, etc when working with Scientific Python. Wanting to bypass that is really not wise! Instead of doing that, please see if you can use [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/), which has a much broader set of packages than what conda can install by default. Besides conda and conda-forge packages are mostly compatible.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you only want to use Selenium, so you need to do: 1. `conda create -n selenium-env -c conda-forge selenium`; and 2. Use it from the `selenium-env`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package in a [virtual environment](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).